# Oracle APEX Custom Login Authentication

Tags: sql, oracle, authentication, triggers, oracle-apex

I have been following this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngOm5uBP1uE&feature=emb_title.

I followed all the codes with my needed variables and they are as follows :

-Creating Table

```
CREATE TABLE  "TB_USERS"
(
    "S_ID" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1), 
    "S_FNAME" varchar2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "S_LNAME" varchar2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "S_Password" varchar2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "S_DOB" date NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "EMAIL" varchar2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    PRIMARY KEY ("S_ID") USING INDEX  ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "USERS_U1" UNIQUE ("EMAIL") USING INDEX  ENABLE
);
```

-Creating Encrypt Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ENCRYPT_PASSWORD
(
    p_username in varchar2,
    p_password  in varchar2)
return varchar2
is
    l_password varchar2(255);
    l_salt  varchar2(30) := 'RANDOM_SALT_STRING';
begin
    l_password := 
    DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(input_string => UPPER(p_username) || l_salt || UPPER(p_password));
    return l_password;
end ENCRYPT_PASSWORD;
```

Both of these sql scripts have been successful but when it comes to declaring the trigger, it gives me the error "**ORA-04070: invalid trigger name ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_200100**". The code I wrote for this script was :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER 'TB_USERS_TRIGGER'
    BEFORE INSERT ON TB_USERS
    for each row
BEGIN 
    :new.EMAIL := upper(:new.EMAIL);
    :new.s_fname := lower(:new.s_fname);
    :new.s_password := ENCRYPT_PASSWORD(upper(:new.email), :new.s_password);
END;
/

Insert into TB_USERS ("EMAIL","S_Password") values ('VASCODIGAMA@GMAIL.COM','rainuma_16');
/
```

Any ideas where I made a mistake or went wrong?

Comment: You have single quotes around the trigger name in the CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER statement. Double quotes will work but better to remove the quotes alltogether, they are no needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove double quotation all together.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE TB_USERS
(
    S_ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1),
    S_FNAME varchar2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    S_LNAME varchar2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    S_Password varchar2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    S_DOB date NOT NULL ENABLE,
    EMAIL varchar2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    PRIMARY KEY (S_ID) USING INDEX  ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT USERS_U1 UNIQUE (EMAIL) USING INDEX  ENABLE
); 

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ENCRYPT_PASSWORD
    (
    p_username in varchar2,
    p_password  in varchar2)
return varchar2
    is
    l_password varchar2(255);
    l_salt  varchar2(30) := 'RANDOM_SALT_STRING';
begin
    l_password :=
    DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(input_string => UPPER(p_username) || l_salt || UPPER(p_password));
    return l_password;
end ENCRYPT_PASSWORD;
   /

Function created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TB_USERS_TRIGGER
    BEFORE INSERT ON TB_USERS
      for each row
BEGIN
    :new.EMAIL := upper(:new.EMAIL);
    :new.s_fname := lower(:new.s_fname);
    :new.s_password := ENCRYPT_PASSWORD(upper(:new.email), :new.s_password);
   END;
/  

Trigger created.
```

Comment: Hi @walrOs , if you find the answer ok, please accept it. If you have any doubt, let me know.